# Exception during ChangeLogicalParent in TabControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, tabcontrol

In my window I have several generic DataTemplates which use DataTriggers to determine data sources and such. This cuts down heavily on xaml duplication in a window with a lot of similar pages. There are TabControls for navigation, with each TabItem housing a ContentControl using one of said templates.

The exception I'm getting is happening while two TabItems on the same TabControl have the same content. I've isolated the problem at the style for a DevExpress GridControl inside the template. The style has DataTriggers which use the tag of the currently selected TabItem to determine both the ItemsSource and ColumnsSource.

The exception: Name:ChangeLogicalParent MSG:Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first. STACK:   at System.Windows.FrameworkContentElement.ChangeLogicalParent(DependencyObject newParent)

Below is an abbreviated version of the xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GridControlTemplate">
...
<dxg:GridControl>
    <dxg:GridControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type dxg:GridControl}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}"
                             Value="{StaticResource FirstTag}">
                    <Setter Property="ColumnsSource" Value="{StaticResource FirstColumns}" />
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding FirstDataSource}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}"
                             Value="{StaticResource SecondTag}">
                    <Setter Property="ColumnsSource" Value="{StaticResource SecondColumns}" />
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding SecondDataSource}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                ...
<TabControl>
<TabItem Header="header 1" Tag="{StaticResource FirstTag}">
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource GridControlTemplate}" Content="{Binding}" />
</TabItem>
<TabItem Header="header 2" Tag="{StaticResource SecondTag}">
    <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource GridControlTemplate}" Content="{Binding}" />
</TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Mind you, this works fine for other groups of TabItems sharing identical ContentTemplates. This TabControl scheme works fine when the GridControl's style doesn't have these DataTriggers. With that in mind, might this be a DevExpress-specific issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your `GridControl` is part of a style held as a static resource. By default resources are shared, that is, the same instance is used by anything that uses the resource. Since both your tabs are using it as their control template, the same GridControl is trying to be made a child of each tab.

You can tell WPF to provide different instances via the `x:Shared` attribute:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GridControlTemplate" x:Shared="false">
```

Comment: No luck with x:Shared. I tried using DynamicResource instead of StaticResource, and that didn't work either. 

I can understand the reasoning behind why this happens; it's just baffling because other tab controls do the exact same thing successfully with a different template, and this one would as well if it weren't for the DataTriggers.